# Hard coding two items in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is the Razor I have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryCode,  ???? , new { @class = "form-control styled-select", id = "CountryCode", name = "CountryCode" })
```

How can I create a Selected List Item of "USA" and "CANADA" in the **????** param ?  I couldn't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new property to your view model to store the list of countries. The type of this property can be a collection of `SelectListItem`.

```
public class CreateSomething
{
   public List<SelectListItem> Countries { set;get;}
   //Your existing properties
   public string CountryCode { set;get; }
}
```

And in your GET action, simply load this property with some data.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm= new CreateSomething();
   vm.Countries= new List<SelectListItem> {
                                        new SelectListItem { Value="USA", Text="USA"},
                                        new SelectListItem { Value="CANADA", Text="Canada"}
   };
   return View(vm);
}
```

and in your view

```
@model CreateSomething
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <label> Select a country </label>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryCode,Model.Countries)
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hard-coded Options**

If you really wanted a hard-coded option, you could create a `SelectList` that contained your two target values :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryCode, new SelectList(new []{ "USA","CANADA" }), ...)
```

Or just explicitly create a `<select>` element to handle it for you, which honestly might be a bit more readable than using the actual HTML Helpers :

```
<select id='CountryCode' name='CountryCode' class='form-control styled-select'>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>CANADA</option>
</select>
```

**Otherwise, use a Model**

If these options don't seem like they would fit your scenario, you should consider using a more MVC-based approach like creating a model to store these properties or storing them in a container like the `ViewBag` and passing them into your View, similar to [the approach in Shyju's response](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40521/shyju).